# angular autocomplete being overlayed by Query-builder container

Tags: css, angular, autocomplete, query-builder

i got problem with my angular autocomplete result list being overlayed by Query-builder container.

relevant part of code:

```
<ng-container *queryInput="let rule; type: 'autocomplete'">
                            <input nbInput type="text" fieldSize="small" shape="rectangle" status="primary"
                                       [(ngModel)]="selectedUser"
                                       (ngModelChange)="changeUsers()"
                                       (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
                                       (click)="click$.next($event.target.value.id)"
                                       [ngbTypeahead]="searchAutocomplete"
                                       [inputFormatter]="formatter"
                                       [resultTemplate]="resultList"
                                />
                                <ng-template #resultList let-r="result" let-t="term">
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="r.firstName + ' ' + r.lastName" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
                                </ng-template>
                        </ng-container>
```

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1wdq.png)

Thx in advance for help!